# Laravel: withCount auth()->user() relationship

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, count, relationship

I my laravel (7.x) application. I have to models `User` and `UserReferral` with `hasMany` relationships.

User.php

```php
class User extends Authenticate implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    public function referrals()
    {
        return $this
            ->hasMany(UserReferral::class)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->skip(0)
            ->take(10);
    }
}
```

UserReferral.php

```php
class UserReferral extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

The list of `Referrals` has `load-more` pagination, `total number of records` and `number of pages`.

I need to get the `total number of records` to calculate the `total number of pages`.

I have already tried this `auth()->user()->withCount('referrals')` but it doesn't work.

Comment: use loadCount instead of withCount because user is already loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have already tried this `auth()->user()->withCount('referrals')` but it doesn't work.

Try to add the `->get();` at the end.